# why CNN model can't learn well the peak from data

Tags: deep-learning, regression, cnn

here I have two different datasets. dataset1 is force plate data and dataset2 is plantar pressure data. dataset1 has shape **(2050,2) and dataset2 has shape**(2050,89). before doing the training I have normalized the data using minmaxscaler() with a scale of 0-1. after normalizing the data then I did data preprocessing for dataset2 using PCA. here I will reduce the data dimension of the plantar pressure to 12, so the current plantar pressure datashape is (2050.12).

here is my CNN model:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler,StandardScaler, RobustScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM,Activation,Dense,BatchNormalization, LeakyReLU, Conv2D, MaxPooling1D, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Flatten, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.losses import sparse_categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop, SGD, Adadelta, Adagrad
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from numpy import zeros, newaxis
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_regression
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_regression,SelectKBest
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
%matplotlib inline

Insole = pd.read_csv('1119_Rwalk40s2_list.txt', header=None, low_memory=False)
SIData =  np.asarray(Insole)

df = pd.read_csv('1119_Rwalk40s2.csv', low_memory=False)
columns = ['Fx','Fz']
selected_df = df[columns]
FCDatas = selected_df[:2050]

SmartInsole = np.array(SIData[:2050])
FCData = np.array(FCDatas)

scaler_x = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler_x.fit(SmartInsole)
xscale = scaler_x.transform(SmartInsole)

scaler_y = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler_y.fit(FCData)
yscale = scaler_y.transform(FCData)

SIDataPCA = xscale
pca = PCA(n_components=0.99)
pca.fit(SIDataPCA)
SIdata_pca = pca.transform(SIDataPCA)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(SIdata_pca, yscale, test_size=0.10, random_state=2)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(64,kernel_size=2,strides=1,padding='same',data_format='channels_last',input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size = 2, strides = 2))

model.add(Conv1D(32,kernel_size=2,strides=1,padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size = 2, strides = 2))

model.add(Conv1D(16,kernel_size=2,strides=1,padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size = 2, strides = 2))

model.add(LSTM(units=16))
model.add(Dense(16,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['mse'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=50, 
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=2)

model.evaluate(SIdata_pca, yscale)
ypred = model.predict(SIdata_pca)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Model Loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper right')
# plt.show()
plt.savefig('Loss Result.png')


x=[]
colors=['red','green','brown','teal','gray','black','maroon','orange','purple']
colors2=['green','red','orange','black','maroon','teal','blue','gray','brown']
for i in range(0,2050):
    x.append(i)
for i in range(0,2):
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
    # plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,yscale[0:2050,i], color=colors[i])
    plt.plot(x,ypred[0:2050,i], markerfacecolor='none',color=colors2[i])
    plt.title('Result for ResNet Regression')
    plt.ylabel('Y value')
    plt.xlabel('Instance')
    plt.legend(['Real value', 'Predicted Value'], loc='upper right')
    plt.savefig('Regression Result.png'[i])
    plt.show()
```

below is the model loss plot
[image]

looking at the training loss model, I don't think there is any indication of overvitting in training, but why can't my model predict high peaks from train data?

prediction results:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Cross posted at https://www.reddit.com/r/deeplearning/comments/zrg6fg/why_cnn_model_cant_learn_well_the_peak_from_data/

Comment: Have you tried using Mean Absolute Error (MAE) instead of Mean Squared Error (MSE) for your loss?

Comment: yes,I have try it. but the predictions still bad

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the data content, but here are some tips according to my past experience:

- The data cycle is around 100 steps. In general, the batch size should be around the data cycle, so that the model learn cycles behavior. Same thing with the LSTM layer: I would have increased its size. 16 neurons could not be enough to memorize a size of 100.
- I don't know if mixing Conv1D and LSTM could reduce the prediction precision as they are very different: Conv1D memorizes shapes and LSTM memorizes dynamics. Maybe you should try one type first.
- The peaks seem to be very short (2 or 3 steps). I would suggest a stride of 1 with a kernel size of 3 to ensure that the neurons learn each step.
- Max Pooling could smooth your data and reduce peak detection because it reduces the values with the closest ones.
- SGD or AdamW could also have better results than Adam.
- The model seems to converge too quickly. Lowering the learning rate and increasing the iterations could improve the results.
- If your data has 50% of values on 0 or 1, maybe you can ignore them and make the training only on the values that matters. This will improve the training results because "useless" data might alter the learning efficiency.
- You may need more data for training. I can't explain why test data are not that good. In general, good training has good accuracy (around 80%) to have a [good generalization](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-deep-learning-models-to-generalize-better-3341a2c5400c). Your situation could be an overfitting one.

In conclusion, the model is a mix of several types of neurons and I'm not able to predict their outcome because their behavior is different. There are probably good reasons to mix them because the loss is quite low. However, I recommend testing one of the proposals above because they could explain why the peaks are not detected very well.

If the parameters are too complex to define, I recommend using a Learned optimizer like [Velo](https://github.com/google/learned_optimization/tree/main/learned_optimization/research/general_lopt).

Comment: I've follow u're suggestion number 3, I set the stride to 1 in maxpooling then now the model can learn peak. but now the problem is the model can't predict data when I use other data

Comment: u can check the new prediction result on these link : https://imgur.com/a/ZrFaTXY

Comment: my model structure now : https://imgur.com/TdpR0qI

Comment: What is the new accuracy value? The result seems not that bad: the peaks are quite well predicted, it is not perfect but it seems better than the previous results.

Comment: the model loss plot : https://imgur.com/X9M0q2r

Comment: training process : https://imgur.com/kHHBO9C

Comment: but why when I testing the model using other data, then the predictions will be bad.u can check this url : https://imgur.com/rbQwxof

Comment: It could be due to a lack of variety in the training data. Are you covering lots of scenarios? In addition to that, I would add some dropout (0.1) to help your model in generalizing.

Comment: I added a drop out on the 3 conv layer ; https://imgur.com/7bVsxPg , along with predictions during training : https://imgur.com/mknmzCt and this is the result of predictions using other data : https://imgur.com/Gk92O6g

Comment: I've added additional tips to the answer. How many samples do you use for training and testing? (a rough order of magnitude)

Comment: the orignal X shape (2050,89) and Y shape is (2050,2). the I spilt the dataset to train and test. X_train.shape (1845, 55), X_test.shape(1845, 55), y_train.shape(1845, 2), y_test.shape(1845, 2)

Comment: Why do the train and the test have the same size? In general, the train/test split is 80%/20% in a random distribution.

Comment: X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(SIdata_pca, yscale, test_size=0.20, random_state=2) I use this method. is it wrong?

Comment: I've try use AdamW() but that will the same, if use other data the predictions will bad

Comment: You're almost there. I've added some tips in the answer.

Comment: Do you have good results? If not, please let me know to provide additional information or other solutions.

Comment: I've try u're suggestions and increasing the dataset from 2050 to 30950. but the predictions still bad when I use other data

Comment: It clearly means that your model is overfitting: it learns "too" well the training data and it is not able to predict production data correctly. You should make it generalizing better with a smaller network, a higher dropout value, or a lower learning rate.

Comment: how about the kernel_size and pool_size? I need change it or no?

Comment: If you see the loss curve, it converges too fast (about 5 epochs to reach 0.02). You should focus on making that curve slower (=more "natural"). It could be the kernel_size or the pool_size: I don't know the data to give you an accurate tip.

Comment: I've solve my problem now, but I need some support for my method. maybe u can help me to support my method. if u have free u can refer to this link https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/117711/adding-data-sequences-as-unique-data-on-dataset-for-regression-model

Comment: Ok, I'll see. Nevertheless, was my answer valid?